# How to map over arrays of arrays in JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have a list of names as an array. These names are then paired, into an array in my App.js

I'm looking to map over these to create a `<ul> containing <li>`s and I'm stuck, any help would be amazing, thanks!

Unfortunately regular map over an array like this won't work... Thanks so!

```
return (
    <ul>
      {pairs.map(pair => (
        <li key={pair}>{pair}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


createPairs() {
    const list = [...this.state.list];

    list.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

    const pairs = [];


    while (list.length >= 2) {
      const pair = [list.pop(), list.pop()];

      pairs.push(pair);
    }

    this.setState({
      pairs
    });
  }
```

Comment: One important thing, how do you want to show paired names in a list?

Comment: So it would be the names of each person in each pair. E.g. {this.state.pairs ? null : console.log(this.state.pairs) (
    <ul>
          {
          this.state.pairs.map(pairs => ( 
              <li key={this.state.pairs[0][0].id}> {pair person 1} {pair person 2}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can potentially use [destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52197528/2178159) within your `map` arguments to extract the components of each pair. Remember to wrap the destructured arguments in parentheses.

```jsx
return (
  <ul>
    {pairs.map(([pair_1, pair_2]) => (
      <li key={pair_1}>{pair_1}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```