# Square Brackets for String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodes, ethereum, metamask

I do not understand why I need to add square brackets around the "account" variable below, for the "accounts" variable constitutes a string.

```
 export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
   return {
    web3: null,
    account: null,
    contractInstance: null
   }
 },
 mounted () {
  web3Cont().then((res) => {
   this.web3 = res
   this.contractInstance = new this.web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress)
   this.web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
    [this.account] = accounts
  })
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array destructuring in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197356/array-destructuring-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you user120242. Yes, I am aware of destructuring, but as I have explained in the comment in the answer below, I did not think that it was possible for the accounts variable to be an array (although the variable is plural, perhaps for legacy reasons), for this constitutes the account (which should be unique) that is currently logged into MetaMask (printing the accounts variable also prints a single account).

Comment: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/accessing-accounts.html  "If the first account in the returned array isn't the account you expected, you should notify the user! In the future, the accounts array may contain more than one account. However, the first account in the array will continue to be considered as the user's "selected" account."

Comment: Thank you user120242! I had missed that.

Comment: After seeing what it is, I'm kind of surprised it doesn't have multiple accounts.  Whether it be related to wallet collections, or browser user profiles, or dApp collections, it would make sense to explicitly support multiple accounts by default

Comment: Well, from what I know, at this moment, users can only select one account at a time (be active at a time) in MetaMask, although they could indeed have multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the name, I'm guessing that `getAccounts` returns **multiple** accounts, presumably as an array (or at least, some kind of iterable). Without the `[]`, you're assigning that array to `this.account`. *With* the `[]`, though, you're using destructuring to pick out just the first account from the array/iterable.

Here's a simpler example:

```js
const accounts = ["a", "b", "c"];
let variable1;
let variable2;

variable1 = accounts;
console.log(typeof variable1, variable1); // "object" ["a", "b", "c"]

[variable2] = accounts;
console.log(typeof variable2, variable2); // "string" "a"
```

I suspect you probably want some API other than `getAccounts` that returns a single account matching some criteria.

Comment: Thank you T.J. Crowder. Although, as you say, the function is called getAccounts in plural, I would have thought logically that there should always be a single account logged in at a time (upon printing out the accounts variable, I am also obtaining a single account). Perhaps, there might be some cases where there could be more than one.