# Copy all elements of an array into individual variables

Tags: node.js

Is there a shorthand way to copy all elements of an array into individual variables in nodejs?

For example, something like this (which doesn't work):

```
var ary = [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6];
var {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} = ...ary;
```

or do I have do do it one at a time, like so:

```
var ary = [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6];
var a = ary[0];
var b = ary[1];
...
var h = ary[7];
```

Comment: Have you tried  : `const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] = [...ary];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array destructuring in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197356/array-destructuring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
var ary = [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6];
var [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] = ary;
```

This syntax is called Destructuring assignment
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: This also works along with debugger's answer, but this one also works in a browser, which is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a sqaure bracket to `...ary`

```
var ary = [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6];
var [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] = [...ary];
```

or just `ary`

```
var [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] = ary;
```

Comment: Neither of these work - debugger's answer is what works

Comment: but I've tested it and it worked :(

Comment: Now that you've edited your answer, it works :)